# Sign up flow broken after correcting an invalid password

Tags: bug, status-completed, sign-up

Steps to repro:

- Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup
- Enter a Display Name, a valid email address, and "unicorn" for a password
- Press enter

  - A tooltip appears, as expected: "Please add one of the following things to make your password stronger: numbers"
- Correct the password to "unicorn42"
- Press enter again

Expected behavior: Go to Sign up confirmation screen

Actual behavior: Nothing happens, errors in the browser console `Uncaught ReferenceError: popupsToClear is not defined`

*Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: This is happening after a user attempts to sign up using the button with an invalid password, then is unable to sign up after meeting the requirements (form breaks). Looking into it now.

Comment: Does it also really say: "please add one of the following" and then just list one? More importantly why doesn't it request that the user adds waffles to the password? :)

Comment: Numbers do not a stronger password make.

Comment: @JonClements I guess that fits in the plural issues these sites have ....

Comment: @Travis it's also 35 minutes in and no one has linked xkcd yet... I'm surprised and somewhat disappointed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a recent refactor of password validation that was causing this. Should be all fixed now.